# PHP ODBC : Updating Form

Tags: php, forms, sql-update, odbc

I have a form and successfully connect them to the database.

Now I'm trying to update the data. Unfortunately, nothing happened when I click the submit button. I'm sure I miss something. Please help me, thank you.

config.php :

```
<?php

$conn=odbc_connect("dsn", "", "");

if (!$conn)
{
exit("Connection Failed : " . $conn);
}

?>
```

This is my code :

```
<?php

include "config.php";

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

error_reporting(-1);

$sql =  odbc_exec( $conn, "SELECT 

        UserId, 
        UserName,
        UserEmail

        FROM DBA.tblUser 
        WHERE UserId='".$_GET['UserId']."'");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $UserId=$_POST["UserId"];
    $UserName=$_POST["UserName"];
    $UserEmail=$_POST["UserEmail"];

    //UPDATE

    $stmt = odbc_exec(  $conn, 
    "UPDATE DBA.tableUsers SET
    UserName = '$UserName',
    UserEmail ='$UserEmail'

    WHERE UserId=$UserId");

    if ($stmt) {

        echo "Update Success";
        echo    $UserName;
        echo    $UserEmail;

    } else {

        "Error : " . odbc_errormsg();
    }
}

?>
```

Form :

```
    <form class="form"  method="post">

    <tr>
    <td class = "userid">User ID</td>
    <td><?php echo $UserId = odbc_result($sql,'UserId');  ?></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
    <td class = "name">User Name<span class="required">&nbsp; * &nbsp;</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="UserName" value="<?php echo $UserName = odbc_result($sql,'UserName');  ?>"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td class = "email">Email<span class="required">&nbsp; * &nbsp;</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="UserEmail" value="<?php echo $UserEmail = odbc_result($sql,'UserEmail');  ?>"></td>
    </tr>

    <button name="submit" type="submit" value ="submit" >Update</button>

</form>
```

Comment: how do you connect to your database `$conn` ? and what's the form you posted? how do you define your $UserId variable ? and you are define `$UserNm` variable then use it as `$UserName` in you query

Comment: I've update my post @hassan

Comment: close your form tag `</form>`

Comment: Still, nothing happened when submit button clicked @hassan

Comment: define this variable `$UserId` before your update query, do you mean by nothing happened that nothing updated in db or nothing showed in your browser ?

Comment: Should I insert the value of `$UserId` ? I've define `$UserId` in updated post. But nothing updated in db or showed in my browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the answer with the same concept and variable.

config.php :

```
<?php

$conn=odbc_connect("dsn", "", "");

if ($conn) {

echo "Connected";

}

if (!$conn) {

exit("Connection Failed : " . $conn);

}

?>
```

code :

```
<?php

include "config.php";

$sql =  odbc_exec( $conn, "SELECT 

        UserId, 
        UserName,
        UserEmail

        FROM DBA.tblUser 
        WHERE UserId='".$_GET['UserId']."'");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $UserName=$_POST["UserName"];
        $UserEmail=$_POST["UserEmail"];

        $stmt = odbc_exec($conn, 
        "UPDATE DBA.tblUser SET
        UserName = '$UserName',
        UserEmail ='$UserEmail'

        WHERE UserId='".$_GET['UserId']."'");

if ($stmt) {

        echo "Update Successfull";
        echo    $UserName;
        echo    $UserEmail;
} 

else {

       "Error : " . odbc_errormsg();
}
}

?>
```

html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Administration</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />   
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/userpage.css" media="screen"/>

<body>

  <content>

  <div class="user-form">

  <div class="user-form-heading">Update User</div><br>

  <form class="form"  method="post">

  <h><table class ="user">


<!-- .................................. Updatable ....................................... -->
<tr>
<td class = "name">User Name<span class="required">&nbsp; * &nbsp;</span></td>
<td><input type="text" name="UserName" value="<?php echo $UserName = odbc_result($sql,'UserName');  ?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class = "userid">User Id</td>
<td><?php echo $UserId = odbc_result($sql,'UserId');  ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class = "email">Email<span class="required">&nbsp; * &nbsp;</span></td>
<td><input type="text" name="UserEmail" value="<?php echo $UserEmail = odbc_result($sql,'UserEmail');  ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<f><button name="submit" type="submit" value ="submit" >UPDATE</button></f>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

</table>
</form>
</div>
</content>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$UserName=$_POST["UserName"];
```

With

```
$UserName=$_POST["UserId"];
```

Why? Simply because in your form, you have name as `UserId` and not `UserName`

```
<input type="text" name="UserId" value="<?php echo $UserName = odbc_result($sql,'UserName');  ?>"></td>
```

Comment: @Far How do you know you are successfully connected to database ? Follow this to setup ODBC http://w3schools.sinsixx.com/php/php_db_odbc.asp.htm

Comment: I've  successfully connected to the db. The following code which is included in the `config.php` will show me the error if the `$conn` failed.  `if (!$conn { exit("Connection Failed : " . $conn); }` . Furthermore, I managed to retrieve the `$UserId` from the db. The only problem is I can't seem to make the update work. @san

Comment: @Far Try with some dummy values, and not take them from form. Just run a php script to insert some values into your table.
If that works, then what happens when you click on "Submit". Does page reload ? check console for any errors or log file ?

Comment: I try update existing value (i changed the email) from table user. But nothing happened. No page reload and value in database did not change. It seems like my **Update** button did not function at all. @sanA